# Python, How do you check how many times an item appears in an array

Tags: python, arrays, text, char, words

I'm making a program that finds every word in a block of text and outputs each word and how many times the word was used.

My current code is here:

```
text = input("Please enter some text ")
terminator = len(text)
    n = 0
    word = ""
    wordlist = []
    while len(text) > 0:
        if word != "":
            wordlist.append(word)
        text = text[n:]
        word = ""
        n = 0
        for char in text:
            if char != " ":
                word = word + char
                n = n + 1
            else:
                text = text[1:]
                break
    for item in wordlist:
        print(item)
```

thanks :)

Comment: Seems like a job for a `collections.Counter` . . .

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

text = input("Please enter some text ")
text = re.sub(' +', ' ', text)
text = text.split(' ')
counter = Counter(text)
```

The line `text = re.sub(' +', ' ', text)` deals with cases where the user enters multiple consecutive spaces.